# Start with a Name

Tags: riddle

Start with a first name

Remove one letter--- Get a letter

From that letter, remove one letter --- get a number

From that number, remove a letter --- get a letter

To that letter, add a letter --- get a (famous) name!

What are the names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite a far-fetched answer:
(Edited after a comment by OP)

Start with a first name

> Phil

Remove one letter--- Get a letter

> Phi (a letter of a Greek alphabet)

From that letter, remove one letter --- get a number

> Pi (a number $\pi\approx3.1416$)

From that number, remove a letter --- get a letter

> I

To that letter, add a letter --- get a (famous) name!

> Xi (Jinping, general secretary of the Chinese Communist Party)

Comment: Vafgnrq bs "C" vs lbh ergnvarq V naq gura nqqrq nabgure yrggre gb trg n snzbhf jbeyq yrnqre???

Comment: @RogerA Jryy, n yrnqre juvpu vf nyfb n yrggre. Hcqngvat zl nafjre.